# Передача значения переменной

Tags: java, android, robospice

Здравствуйте подскажите как правильно передать значения переменной, вот код

```
public class MainActivity extends WorkService {
   public int buy;

   public  class TextRequestListener implements RequestListener<String> {

        @Override
        public void onRequestFailure(SpiceException spiceException) {
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d(TAG,"failure");
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestSuccess(final String result) {
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d(TAG,"success");
            Log.d(TAG,result);
            //парсинг ответа, JSON
            try {
                dataJsonObj = new JSONObject(result);

                JSONObject sys = dataJsonObj.getJSONObject("query");
                JSONObject sys1 = sys.getJSONObject("results");
                JSONObject sys2 = sys1.getJSONObject("rate");

                buy = sys2.getInt("Ask");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.d(TAG,"buy = " + buy);
        }
    }

   public int getBuy(){
    return buy;
}`
```

Класс TextRequestListener вложен в класс `MainActivity`. Мне нужно передать вот эту строчку **buy = sys2.getInt("Ask");** в другой класс. Пытался сделать так, но не получается

```
MainActivity a = new MainActivity();
MainActivity.TextRequestListener b = a.new TextRequestListener();
int buy = b.buy;
Log.d(TAG, "buy= " + buy);
```

или

```
MainActivity main = (MainActivity)getActivity();
int s = main.getBuy();
```

в двух случаях получаю ноль.

Comment: "в другой класс" - это другая активити/сервис, или просто другой объект в той же активити?

Comment: в фрагмент, в метод onCreateView

Answer (score 2):

В фрагменте есть специальный метод `getActivity();` который возвращает вам активити, к которой присоединен данный фрагмент.
У вас есть множество способов получить нужную вам переменную, например создав геттер:

```
public int getBuy(){
return buy;
}
```

И вызывать примерно следующим образом: 
`int buy = getActivity().getBuy();`//псевдокод, не проверял, но мысль такая.

p.s. Никогда не создавайте экземпляр активити - у вас не получится.

`MainActivity a = new MainActivity();` - этого делать никогда не нужно.

Comment: не получается, в MainActivity создал public int getBuy(){
return buy;
}

Comment: потом в фрагменте его вызвал                                                               MainActivity main = (MainActivity)getActivity();
int s = main.getBuy();  так же получаю 0.                                                      Выложил полный код, что я делаю не так???

Comment: [здесь ссылка, надеюсь она сможет помочь](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/fragments.php)

Comment: К слову, проверяли приходящий к вам JSON?Может там вам 0 и приходит?

Comment: проверял, в классе TextRequestListener, строчка Log.d(TAG,"buy = " + buy); приходит число 337

Comment: в метод public int getBuy(){ return buy; } в MainActivity  уже почему то передается ноль

Comment: попробуйте создать setter для переменной buy
В локальную переменную вы запоминаете число, полученное из JSON и затем делаете set для глобальной переменной.

Comment: Если это не поможет - [железобетонный метод](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html?hl=ru)
Создание обратного вызова.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так:
  В активити:

```
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("название", переменная);
    фрагмент.setArguments(bundle);
```

В фрагменте:

```
    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    перменная в фрагменте = bundle.getString("название");
```